# How can I measure the size of my data in database tables?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a number of tables containing data (in Postgres), and would like to know how 'big' my data is. How can I measure this?

The only ways I can think of is to either:

Calculate the size of each row (based on the data types) and multiply by the number of rows (but this won't be accurate when my data is normalized)

or:

Denormalize the data with a bunch of joins and export the result to CSV and look at the size of the file.

Is there another (easier) way to do this?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE

Comment: Not familiar with postgres, but i am assuming that like other platforms, there are statistics and metadata to query.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Schema_Size

Comment: Read here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/monitoring-stats.html

Answer (score 3):

The built in function [`pg_database_size()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html) can be used to get the size of an entire database (including indexes, built in schemas, etc).

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size( current_database() ) );
```